# MFL - Message Format Language

Tags: integration, integration-testing, message, oracle-service-bus

What is MFL? Why is it used? Does it actually convert data from one encoding to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13159_01/osb/docs10gr3/consolehelp/mfls.html):

> A Message Format Language (MFL)
>   document is a specialized XML document
>   used to describe the layout of binary
>   data. It is an Oracle proprietary
>   language used to define rules to
>   transform formatted binary data into
>   XML data.

Comment: yes i got that from the Oracle docs too, What i want to know is does it actually do any characterset conversion from ebcdic to ascii and vice versa?

Comment: Well it answers your first question, and arguably the second! Might want to edit your question to clarify CHARACTER encoding - I missed that anyway. :-) It looks like MFL encoding can be set with Orcale's Format Builder tool via Tools->Options: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14981-01/wli/docs1031/fbhelp/property.html. Not sure exactly what encoding schemes they have built-in - you'll have to grab a copy and see what's there, unless someone else here happens to know that.